# Как правильно вывести новость в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет, ребята подскажите как мне правильно вывести 5 новостей из базы.. пример в скриншоте

model

```
    public static function getFiveArticlesForSportPit()
{
    return self::find()
        ->where(['status' => self::STATUS_ON])
        ->asArray()
        ->limit('5')
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
        ->all();
}
```

view

```
<div class="news">
<?php foreach ($fiveArticles as $article) : ?>
    <div class="new-long">
        <div class="new-long-img">
            <?= Html::img('/web/uploads/articles/' . Articles::getImageTitle($article['img_id']), ['width' => '320', 'height' => '240']) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="new-long-title">
            <?= $article['title'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="new-long-text">
            <?= $article['text'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="new-long-date">
            <?= $article['created_at'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="new-long-readmore">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="new-short">
        <div class="new-short-img">
            <?= Html::img('/web/uploads/articles/' . Articles::getImageTitle($article['img_id']), ['width' => '320', 'height' => '240']) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="new-short-title">
            <?= $article['title'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="new-short-description">
            <?= $article['text'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="new-short-date">
            <?= $article['created_at'] ?>
        </div>
        <div class="readmore">

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сейчас то что не так? В коде всё правильно

Comment: получается что верхний и нижний div блоки дублируется и в итоги получается вывод 10 статей

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос

```
<?php foreach ($fiveArticles as $i => $article) : ?>

<?php if ($i === 0): ?>
--- new-long
<?php continue; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

-- new-short

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Либо как в этом [ресурсе](https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html)

Comment: А причем `if ($i === 0)` continue ? Каким образом это влияет на вывод 5 статей вместо 10? Вопрос с ответом вообще не вяжутся

Comment: Где:
$fiveArticles - массив записей
$i - порядковый номер (не попутать с id, просто номер записи в массиве по порядку начиная с 0)
$article - сама запись 
==== - означает жесткую проверку с 0.Соответственно в цикле мы проверяем, если запись первая (все записи идут по порядку начиная с 0), то делаем соответствующие действия.

Comment: Каким образом это влияет на вывод 5 статей вместо 10?

Comment: с помощью этой проверки у меня теперь все правильно выводит, если есть другое решение ПОДСКАЖИТЕ???

Comment: Вопрос невнятен и не демонстрирует проблему ровным счетом никак. Судя по коду в ответе - он никак с вопросом не связан, либо были упущенные какие-то детали, которые были у тебя в голове, но ты их не описал. Тем более ты приложил ссылку на masonry зачем-то, в которой предполагается будет ответ, но там его нет. там вообще ничего про yii2 и php нет, а в вопросе masonry  ты даже не упоминал. В общем ты непонятно что задал и непонятно на что сам и ответил))